# Which way to map @ManyToMany is better: collections or entity class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I am having a problem with choosing which way is the most efficient to map Many-To-Many relationship between tables in hibernate, jpa in my Spring Boot, Spring Data Jpa project. For example I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSITIONS")
public class Position {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "POSITION_EMPLOYEE",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "POSITION_ID", foreignKey =  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_POSITION"),
                nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", foreignKey =  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPLOYEE"),
                nullable = false)
    )
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private Set<Position> positions = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Write now they are mapped by using collection, but maybe it would be better if I created an entity class for Many-To-Many table? Like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSITION_EMPLOYEE")
public class PositionEmployee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "POSITION_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey =  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_POSITION"))
    private Position position;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = false, foreignKey =  @ForeignKey(name = "FK_EMPLOYEE"))
    private Employee employee;
}
```

I am afraid that when I will add employee or position to the collection, hibernate might fetch all data from the DB because of this kind of syntax:

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employees.add(employee);
        employee.getPositions().add(this);
    }
```

In this line `employee.getPositions().add(this)` I will fetch all the data from DB even if I will use `FetchType.Lazy` because I am invoking the collection by `employee.getPositions()` (well, I think it's true if I understand correctly how fetch types are working). So instead of this I think I can do something like this:

```
PositionEmployee positionEmployee = new PositionEmployee();
positionEmployee.setEmployee(employee);
positionEmployee.setPosition(position);
    
serviceClass.save(positionEmployee);
```

I know about **Domain events** in Spring Data Jpa, so maybe i should use it?

Comment: In the setup right now, `Position` is the "owning" side of the relation. This means that `this.employees.add(employee);` should be sufficient; a subsequent `.save(...)` should cascade the save down to the many-to-many relation. --- While it is possible to model the join-table explicitly, this is normally not done in JPA.

Comment: Not sure on Hibernate, but other providers (EclipseLink) support change tracking on lists, so allow calling employees.add(employee) and employee.getPositions().add(this) without fetching the lazy collection underneath (but I wouldn't suggest using a set). Pick the model that best suits your use cases and adapt for performance later if it really is an issue - you'll find you really only need to set the owning side of a relationship: JPA utilities can check if the other, non-owning side was fetched already to allow you to decide if you need to add it to maintain the cached object